# How to copy a draw area into a CImage

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am a newbie to MFC.

I am trying to copy a CScrollView dialog (which has drawn contents) into a image and then save that to a image as bmp or jpg or tiff.

I know how to save the CImage into a file, but i am unable to copy the draw area into a new CImage object. I know the procedure to copy. but i am unable to get in the code.

1. I need to get the CDC of the drawn area.
2. Create a new DC and copy that to new DC or an image.
3. Save the image.

Any pointers please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `CImage` based on Window size, and just draw on that image with `BitBlt`. Use `CImage::GetDC()` to obtain `HDC`, don't forget to call `CImage::ReleaseDC()` later.

```
CDC *pDC; //or use CClientDC, CPaintDC etc.
//do all drawings on pDC first
//pDC->TextOut(0,0,L"hello world")...

CRect rc;
GetClientRect(&rc);

CImage image;
image.Create(rc.Width(), rc.Height(), 32);

HDC imageHDC = image.GetDC(); 
::BitBlt(imageHDC, 0, 0, rc.Width(), rc.Height(), pDC->GetSafeHdc(), 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
image.Save(L"fileName.jpg", GUID_NULL);
image.ReleaseDC();
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply. I appreciate it. My dialog is already drawn in a draw() function.  I tried storing the CDC object in the draw method and use it here.  But, I am getting a blank image.   So how to get the context of already drawn object, it would be of great helpif you give me some more pointers?

Comment: Probably you are not doing any drawings on `CDC`. Are you trying to take screen shot of a window?

Comment: Yes, I am taking screenshot of the window. Anyway i got it worked by creating a CDC *SourceHDC = this.GetDC(); and i got the handle.       Thank you so much. You made my day.. :-)

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, hey, old question, but I need to know whether can I create CDC like this `CDC *pDC = new CDC;`

Comment: @shan, If you are in a `CWnd` function, use `CClientDC dc(this);`, for example, `CMyWindow::foo(){CClientDC dc(this); dc.Rectangle(...);}` or use `CPaintDC dc(this);` if you are in `CWnd::OnPaint`. If you may need "memory dc", then use `CDC memdc; memdc.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc); ...`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani thanks for the comment. The thing is, I'm drawing multiple shapes in my `OnPaint()` function. But I need to save only one shape(based on user's selection) into an image. If I use `CPaintDC`, it draws everything to the image. Do you have any suggestion to do this? I will post this as a question if you want

Comment: @shan, You have to start a new question. You want to declare `CDC m_memdc;` as a member function (it doesn't have to be a pointer). Call `memdc.CreateCompatibileDC` and draw everything on `memdc`, then paint `memdc` on to `dc` when `OnPaint` is called.